# Java 8 HttpClient 4.5 Handling cookies with BasicCookieStore

Tags: java, java-8, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, cookiestore

How can I do that?

```
HttpClientBuilder client = HttpClientBuilder.create();
HttpResponse response = null;
HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
client.setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore);

response = client.build().execute(get);
cookieStore = context.getCookieStore();
```

It gives me: CookieStore cannot be converted to BasicCookieStore. I can't use CookieStore interface instead of BasicCookieStore, because in my other classes shows me "Interfaces can't be instantiated".

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] in order to get a reasonable and fast responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think casting will help you.

```
BasicCookieStore cookieStore = (BasicCookieStore) context.getCookieStore();
```